# How do I dynamically access ActiveRecord instance attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Basically I'm doing a find an replace over a set of text with data from the db, but the replacement tags are generated by the user and can be any of a huge selection.

How do you access a model record when the field name is in a variable

Normal access is

```
var = model.field_name
```

But in my code, I would like to do something like this

```
replacement_tags.each do |tag|
  content = content.gsub(/tag/, model.|access attribute with same name as tag|
end
```

so if tags were firstname, lastname the block would run gsub for model.firstname and model.lastname consecutively.

I don't mind if I'm going about this the wrong way, as long as there is some way to achieve these results

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you're calling instance methods in Ruby, you are not calling anything, you're *sending messages* to the receiver.

`user.first_name` can be read as "send message to this `user` object that asks it to return its first name"

Equipped with this knowledge and [this documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-send), you can easily write your code as

```
replacement_tags.each do |tag|
  content = content.gsub(/tag/, model.send(tag.to_sym))
end
```

Comment: You may want to use `model.__send__(tag.to_sym)` in case `.send` was overriden

Comment: Thanks to you both. That's perfect.